# How to clone adjacency list in c++?

Tags: c++, graph, adjacency-list

I have trying to make a clone of adjacency list in c++. But couldn't possibly do so.
I have declared using:

```
vector<int> adj[N]; // N is the number of vertices
```

How do I make the clone of this list in c++ ?

I tried looking up on the web. But couldn't find any answer. Requesting my fellow mates to answer this question.

Comment: `vector<int> clone[N]; std::copy(std::begin(adj), std::end(adj), std::begin(clone));`

Comment: Use `vector<vector<int>>` instead, and, simply, `adj2=adj`?

Comment: Or `std::array<std::vector<int>, N>` for an array of vectors and `ajd2=adj` for the copy.

Comment: Don't learn C++ from garbage coding websites that teach nonsensical `vector<int>[N]`. Prefer a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to avoid using old c style arrays in c++ in favor of only [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (or [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for static sized arrays).
Your adjacency list could be implemented using:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj(N);
```

This is using the [`std::vector` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that accepts a size, and enables `N` to be dynamic (whereas in your code it must be known at compile time because c++ does not support VLAs - variable length arrays).

Cloning is easy:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> clone = adj;
```

---

If you must use a c style array, you can clone it with:

```
vector<int> clone[N]; 
std::copy(std::begin(adj), std::end(adj), std::begin(clone));
```

**A side note:** better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).